# Need to automate de creation of a html Family Tree

Tags: html

I need do automate (is that a word?) the creation of a Family Tree in html. I don't have many knowledge of this language, so I need a simple code (or guidelines to it) that allows me to create a simple family tree. Just the basic stuff like a box for the Name and DOB of a person and a arrow pointing to its relatives (children, parents and brothers).

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use one of the many existing services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the term `automate` is used here. I suppose you are trying to create the HTML elements without actually having it in the HTML page. So, here is a way you can create a HTML and the tree structure subsequently.

```
var div = $("<div />")
div.append("<div id='another' />")
div.append("<div id='next' />")
div.appendTo($('body'));
```

This create a div, puts two other div inside it, and is appended in the body tag.